# Elasticsearch Query String Query not working with synonym analyzer

Tags: java, elasticsearch, analyzer, synonym

I am trying to configure elastic search with synonyms.

These are my settings:

```
                "analysis": {
                    "analyzer": {
                        "category_synonym": {
                            "tokenizer": "whitespace",
                            "filter": [
                                "synonym_filter"
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "filter": {
                        "synonym_filter": {
                            "type": "synonym",
                            "synonyms_path": "synonyms.txt"
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Mappings config:

```
        "category": {
            "properties": {
                "name": {
                    "type":"string",
                    "search_analyzer" : "category_synonym",
                    "index_analyzer" : "standard",
                    "fields": {
                        "raw": {
                            "type":  "string",
                            "index": "not_analyzed"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

And the list of my synonyms

```
film => video,
ooh => panels , poster,
commercial => advertisement,
print => magazine
```

I must say that I am using Elasticsearch Java API. 
I am using `QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery` because this is the only way how I set analyzers to my request.
So, when I am making:

```
QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery("name:film").analyzer(analyzer)
```

It returns me

```
[
  {
    "id": 71,
    "name": "Pitch video",
    "description": "... ",
    "parent": null
  },
  {
    "id": 25,
    "name": "Video",
    "description": "... ",
    "parent": null
  }
]
```

That is perfect for me, but when I am calling something like this

```
QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery("name:vid").analyzer(analyzer)
```

I expect that it should return same objects, but there is nothing: `[]`

So, I added asterisk to `queryStringQuery`:

```
QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery("name:vid*").analyzer(analyzer)
```

Works well, but now

```
QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery("name:film*").analyzer(analyzer)
```

returns me `[]`

So, how can I configure my elastic search that it will return same objects when I am searching `video`, `vid`, `film` and `fil`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm, I don't think Elasticsearch will know to "translate" `fil` into `vid` :-). So, I think you need `edgeNGram`s for this, both at indexing and search time.

```
PUT test
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "category_synonym": {
          "tokenizer": "whitespace",
          "filter": [
            "synonym_filter",
            "my_edgeNGram_filter"
          ]
        },
        "standard_edgeNGram": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "synonym_filter",
            "my_edgeNGram_filter"
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "synonym_filter": {
          "type": "synonym",
          "synonyms_path": "synonyms.txt"
        },
        "my_edgeNGram_filter": {
          "type": "edgeNGram",
          "min_gram": 2,
          "max_gram": 8
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "test": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "category_synonym",
          "index_analyzer": "standard_edgeNGram",
          "fields": {
            "raw": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

POST test/test/1
{"name": "Pitch video"}
POST test/test/2
{"name": "Video"}

GET /test/test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "name:fil"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Worked! Thanks Andrei!

Comment: Has "index_analyzer" been replaced with something else? When I try to use that property it throws an error. When I try to use "search_analyzer" i get an error stating I can't use the synonyms filter during runtime mode.